# Tomcat Maven Plugin: shutdown when running on non-standard port

Tags: maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using a software which comes as a source tarball and maven pom.xml which builds a war and eventually gets run like this:

```
 mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=1234
```

When I run this command in the background, I am unable to subsequently shutdown this server using

```
 mvn tomcat:shutdown -Dmaven.tomcat.port=1234
```

I have not found a way to define a shutdown port when starting, nor any documentation if the tomcat which is started that way uses any other of the ports that are normally used in the standard Tomcat configuration, especially the shutdown port and shutdown string. It looks as if not, but can anyone confirm this? Does this mean then that the only way to shutdown the server is by explicitly killing the process? But what is the purpose of the tomcat:shutdown then?